# Select option selected keyword not working

Tags: html, angular, dropdown, ngmodel

in my html use select options drop-down list but it's not working in my Angular project

```
 <td>
 <select type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="addressDetails.AddressTypeId"id="AddressTypeId" formControlName="AddressTypeId" style="height:29px; width:200px; padding:3px">
 <option disabled selected value > -- select an option -- </option>
 <option *ngFor="let addressType of addressTypeDetails" value={{addressType.AddressTypeID}}>
             {{addressType.AddressType}} </option>
 </select>
 </td>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. "Not working" is not a very useful description of a problem.

Comment: `selected` attribute is useless in Angular : you must provide your `ngModel` with the default value you want.

Comment: "it's not working" does not clearly explain what is your problem. Please make sure to provide any proper error messages you get.

Comment: no any error message, already bind array's data, but i want to set a default value for the drop-down list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding ngmodel of array object, which is incorrect. I have created a sample example, please check on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r16izl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)
I created addressDetail object to bind the with ngModel. please check the html below.
Here is the component code.

```js
addressTypeDetails = [{AddressTypeID:1,AddressType:'first'},{AddressTypeID:2,AddressType:'second'}]
  addressDetail = {addressTypeId:0}
```

Here is the Html Code.

```js
 <select type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="addressDetail.addressTypeId" id="AddressTypeId"  style="height:29px; width:200px; padding:3px">
 <option > -- select an option -- </option>
 <option *ngFor="let addressType of addressTypeDetails" value={{addressType.AddressTypeID}}>
             {{addressType.AddressType}} </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: it's already bind array's properties , but can't bind default value for drop-down list

Comment: are you talking about default selected value, I have set the default value  in addressTypeId field and that is selected on the screen. please check the stackblitz example.

Comment: `<option disabled selected **value = 0**  > -- select an option -- </option>` need to give value = 0

Comment: I have updated the code, the changed code is: if there is no value then it is null and set null value in the option element. <option value="null" > -- select an option -- </option>

Comment: Yes that also work, but just for your info,  as a practice should follow null for non dB text. Because if server return null value then this will not work, I am talking about application level not for this case.